# Azure Traffic Manager returns 503 but Cloud Service is working, what is missing?

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I have a cloud service that runs a worker role (self host owin middleware).  The cloud service endpoint mysubdomain.cloudapp.net returns but when I go through mysubdomain.trafficmanager.net I consistently get a 503 returned.

Couple additional points:

- For the time being I am just doing HTTP and not HTTPS but will change in future
- I only have one cloud service (with 4 instances) deployed
- port for the worker role/owin selfhost is 80 (public port) bound to a private port of 8088

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Traffic Manager works at the DNS level, not the network level.  It uses DNS to direct users to the correct service endpoint, and users then connect to that endpoint **directly**.

503 is an HTTP-level status code.  Since Traffic Manager works at the DNS level, it cannot be coming from Traffic Manager, it must be coming from your application.

So, please check whether your application is configured to accept requests using the mysubdomain.trafficmanager.net subdomain, rather than the subdomain.cloudapp.net subdomain.

You should also check that your endpoints in Traffic Manager are showing as 'online'.  If not, Traffic Manager's health probes are failing, and you should fix that first.

I hope this helps!